# Multiple stores with a combined store Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, multistore, store-view

We would like to have 3 different stores - these would be set up as Multiple stores in one Magento installation as recommended.  But the tricky part is:

**Question : Can we have a combination of these 3 stores in one store on the same installation?**

For example 
we have a store called: 1) surfboards,  2) wetsuits and 3) standupboards.  But let's say we want a 4th store called watersports.  Is it possible to combine the 3 stores catalogs into this combined watersports store?

I haven't been able to find anything about this yet, perhaps I am asking the wrong questions in my searches

Answer (score 0):

By combination of the 3 stores into one, I guess that you mean having all the products from the 3 first stores into the 4th one.

To make this happen, you will actually create a 4th multiple store. You can manage the 4 of them from the same administration, and for each item, you can select what store it will be applied to. So your surfboard will be part of store 1 and 4, your wetsuit will be part of 2 and 4, etc...

The same thing works for the categories, and the different configuration. You can have a "Global" scope, or a "Store" scope, that will only apply to the given website.